# Android list all files in package

Tags: java, android, getresource

I got a resource package like:

```
com.xxx.res
|- res1-
|      |- a
|      |- b
|- c
|- d
|- Test.java
```

I want to list all files in package `com.xxx.res`, the source code of `Test.java` like below:

```
public static void listRes(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File f : files) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            listRes(f);
        } else {
            System.out.println(f.getPath());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String base = Test.class.getResource("").getPath();
    File root = new File(base);
    listRes(root);
}
```

It works fine with pure java application, but in Android, the File `root` always not exists. Can anyone tell me what is wrong or I've missed something?

Comment: There are no files in a package. There are *resources* in a package, but their number is not finite or enumerable unless the package is sealed.

Comment: @EJP Does it means I can't list `files` but can get the resources via `resource name` (actually I thought resource name is file path) in Android? Can you tell me more about this? Thanks a lot.